# Nominatim setup.sh permission denied

Tags: postgresql, unix, nominatim

I followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) to install Nominatim. The installation procedure was not too complicated until the import process. I keep getting this same error over and over

```
CREATE FUNCTION
ERROR:  could not access file "~/Nominatim/module/nominatim.so":      Permission denied
ERROR: pgsql returned with error code (3)
pgsql returned with error code (3)
```

I tried doing as the tutorial proposed

```
 chmod +x Nominatim
 chmod +x Nominatim/module
```

Still didn't want to work. Got pissed and did `chmod -R 777 Nominatim && chown -R user:usergroup`. Nothing.

Finally, tried restarting and still nothing.

I am on ubuntu 14.04 using postgresql 9.3 postgis 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb.

The tutorial wasn't clear enough on when to STOP for giving permissions.
In fact, I had to give my whole home folder the permission `chmod +x user`. They say that all parent require the execute permission but I wasn't about to give `+x` to my `/usr` folder.

Anyways. There. `chmod +x /usr/user`